# Get x1,x2 provided that x belongs to [x1,x2]

Tags: python

Given:

```
xvalues = [0.0, 1829.0, 3658.0, 5487.0]
```

and

```
nodesF = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0.5, 0, 0], [3, 5487, 0, 0]]
```

I want to loop over `nodesF` and return `x1` and `x2` values which every `x` of `nodesF` lie between, i.e. x belongs to `[x1,x2]` with `x1<x2`.

My code is:

```
     for nodeID, x, y, z in nodesF:
        x2= min(value for value in xvalues if value >= x)
        x1= max(value for value in xvalues if value <= x)
        if x1==x2:
            x1=None
            x2=None
            x2= min(value for value in xvalues if value > x)
            x1= max(value for value in xvalues if value <= x)
            if x2==None or x2<=x1:
                x2= min(value for value in xvalues if value >= x)
                x1= max(value for value in xvalues if value < x)
            elif x1==None or x2<=x1:
                print "Error"
```

For x=5487 I get:

> x2= min(value for value in xvalues if value > x) ValueError: min() arg
>   is an empty sequence.

So my question is how do get pass this error? if I could just set `x2=None` when `min()` is empty it would be OK! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you'll need to do the check the list yourself:

```
valid_values = [value for value in xvalues if value > x] #changed >= by >
if valid_values:
    x2 = min(valid_values)
else:
    x2 = None
```

Or you could catch the error after the fact:

```
try:
    x2 = min(value for value in xvalues if value > x) #changed >= by >
except ValueError:
    x2 = None
```

Answer (score 0):

So two lines might seem a little terse, but I hope you like it:

```
r = zip([float('-inf')] + xvalues, xvalues + [float('inf')])
```

which produces this:

```
In [104]: print r
Out[104]: [(-inf, 0.0), (0.0, 1829.0), (1829.0, 3658.0), (3658.0, 5487.0), (5487.0, inf)]
```

Then get your ranges like this:

```
[[filter(lambda l: l[0] < n <= l[1], r)[0] for n in m] for m in nodesF]
```

which produces this:

```
Out[102]: 
[[(0.0, 1829.0), (-inf, 0.0), (-inf, 0.0), (-inf, 0.0)],
[(0.0, 1829.0), (0.0, 1829.0), (-inf, 0.0), (-inf, 0.0)],
[(0.0, 1829.0), (3658.0, 5487.0), (-inf, 0.0), (-inf, 0.0)]]
```